# How to Concatenate values present in Multiple fields and display it as single value in target field

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to auto-populate the Opportunity Name field based on the data entered during Opp creation.

```
Field A = Picklist
Field B = Picklist
Field C = Lookup (Account Name)
```

```
Logic: Opp Name = (Field A (first letter of Field A) + Field B + Field C)
```

What I have tried:
Created a Workflow rule to update the Name field once the record is created. Below is the Logic:

```
Opp Name: Field A&"-"&Field B&"-"&Field C
```

I am not sure how to display only the first letter of Field A. If Field A has a value "SFDC", I need only 'S' to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Find `LEFT` on this page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5#LEFT (or in the formula builder you have help links too).

Since these are picklists it might have to be something like

```
LEFT(TEXT(FieldA__c), 1) & " - " & TEXT(FieldB__c) & " - " & Account.Name
```

You might want to wrap it in another `LEFT(..., 120)` if the whole thing can grow long (or whatever is the max on `Opportunity.Name`)